# PhysicsWorld: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

i'm trying to find physicsBody on scene using raycasting, but I'm getting the following error message:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

It doesn't make sense because I unwrap scene and world and I even println it's content and it's not nil.

The code is called from `SKNode::update()` called by `SKScene::update()` function.

```
    var rotation: Float = Float(zRotation)
    var rayStart: CGPoint = CGPointMake(10, 10)
    var rayEnd: CGPoint = CGPointMake( CGFloat(visibilityRange * CGFloat(cosf(rotation))), CGFloat(visibilityRange * CGFloat(sinf(rotation))) )

    println("rayStart: \(rayStart) --- rayEnd: \(rayEnd)")
    println("scene: \(scene) --- world: \(scene.physicsWorld)")

    if let scene = scene
    {
        if let world = scene.physicsWorld
        {
            println("again: scene: \(scene) --- world: \(world)")
            var body: SKPhysicsBody = scene.physicsWorld.bodyAlongRayStart(rayStart, end: rayEnd)
        }
    }
```

Full error message:

```
<SKScene> name:'(null)' frame:{{0, 0}, {320, 568}} - <PKPhysicsWorld: 0x7ff3b9571970>
rayStart: (10.0,10.0) --- rayEnd: (300.0,0.0)
scene: <SKScene> name:'(null)' frame:{{0, 0}, {320, 568}} --- world: <PKPhysicsWorld: 0x7ff3b9571970>
again: scene: <SKScene> name:'(null)' frame:{{0, 0}, {320, 568}} --- world: <PKPhysicsWorld: 0x7ff3b9571970>
Chance
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Comment: This was interesting: http://jamesonquave.com/blog/understanding-the-fatal-error-cant-unwrap-optional-none-errors-in-swift/

Comment: Can you specify what line the error is on?

Comment: I had this same issue. In my case, it was a scope issue. `var player: SKShapeNode!` was in the GameScene scope, and then when setting up physics, I introduced it to the `didMove(to: view)` scope with `let player = ...`. Changing it to just `player = ...` in `didMove` fixed the scope issue and resolved the nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bodyAlongRayStart:end:` returns `nil` if it finds no physics bodies along the ray. Because of this, it's declared as returning an (implicitly unwrapped) optional type. You're forcing it into a variable of non-optional type, so when it turns out to be nil, you get that error.

Instead, assign to an optional type and check the optional before using it, or assign through optional binding (`if-let`).

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I missed the exclamation mark in the documentation: func bodyAlongRayStart(...) -> SKPhysicsBody!

Comment: This was my deleted comment, but I thought it was something else. For instance, `let scene=scene` should be making a copy of the `scene` object, which would not affect the original instance.  I'm not sure what implications this might have in the program.